# Android changing particular image in gridview based on button click in next activity

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have implemented an app in which i have a grdiview of images, each of which uses an onItemClickListener to redirect to another activity with 4 buttons. How can i make the image of that particular grdiview item change, based on which button is clicked on the corresponding activity which is opened. In other words, I am trying to make the result of one activity affect the appearence of the previous activity. I am aware that we can use static to do the same with variable, but in this case, I am not sure of what to do as static doesnt seem to work with gridview.
Thanks

Comment: Here's a nice example on how to use `onActivityResult()` to pass data from an activity, to a previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1271435

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change anyting in activity `A`, based on result from activity `B` then activity `A` should use `startActivityForResult()` to start `B` and then process `B`'s result in `onActivityResult()`.

[See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) to get more information.